# r.js builds my modules, but I can not get the result to run in the browser

Tags: requirejs, amd, r.js

I have a little requirejs project with the following directory structure.

```
├── index.html
└── js
    ├── bob.js
    ├── build.js
    ├── jquery.js
    ├── main-built.js
    ├── main.js
    └── require.js
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Title</title>
        <script data-main="js/main-built.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

js/main.js

```
define(function () {
    return 'bob';
});
```

js/build.js

```
({
    name: 'main',
    baseUrl: '.',
    out: 'main-built.js'
})
```

js/main.js

```
define(function (require) {
    var $ = require('jquery'),
        bob = require('bob');

    $(function () {
        $(':header').text(bob);
    });
});
```

I run r.js like so:

```
./r.js -o js/build.js
```

It successfully builds, but the code doesn't execute in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To actually run the darn thing, you have to `require` the main module at the toplevel.

Adding this script somewhere in index.html fixes the problem

```
<script>require(['main'])</script>
```

Comment: I am running across the same issue.  I tried to require the main module, but instead the browser tried to request main.js from the baseUrl.  Any ideas?